# Upload three versions of an image, full size, thumbnail and resized

Tags: php, file-upload, crop, watermark, resize-image

So far, I've been uploading one image by hand (FTP to the server when live, locally moving a file), and then resizing them on the fly using the `img` tag's `width` and `height` properties to resize them. Well, the images don't look good, because I need a square, cropped 100px version as a thumbnail, and then a 800px wide version for the view image page, and then finally the full-size original image for HD viewing, but I also need to apply a watermark, but only to the full res version. And I need help with an image upload script. Any sort of file upload, really. I've looked at tutorials, and they don't seem to make too much sense. Furthermore, I need to drop all three versions into a database row (which I think I can figure out). I know that I need to use something like $_FILE to do it, but I'm just really confused to the actual usage and the cropping/resizing/watermarking part really has me stumped. Solutions, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

### File uploading

- Upload using a simple HTML form and use PHP to manipulate the image. [Example](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php)
- Read all the images stored in a directory and convert them in a batch. [Example](http://www.redips.net/php/resize-images/)

### Image re-sizing

- Use ImageMagick or GD library to resize images. [Example](http://www.fliquidstudios.com/2009/05/07/resizing-images-in-php-with-gd-and-imagick/)
- Use any of the same libraries to watermark the images. [Example](http://www.rubblewebs.co.uk/imagemagick/compair.php)

In all, you need to combine all these in order to upload, resize and watermark all in one go.

Answer (score 0):

For the resizing, watermark etc, you should look at ImageMagic

Comment: I'll look into it. What of the uploading, though?